# Get all Custom posts beginning with letter A

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type(event) with a custom taxonomies(event_countries).

http://educationgate.org/en/event_countries/united-arab-emirates/

I want to get all the custom posts that bening with the letter A.

The issue is i want to get this through a url string.

I have tried http://educationgate.org/en/event_countries/united-arab-emirates?orderby=title&order=ASC&s=A

But this is going to the search page and show all posts.

Can somebody help?

Comment: See this answer, It must help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716312/get-all-posts-beginning-with-letter-a

Comment: Thanks Alexander Z. But i dont know how to use "post_where" since i dont know where to use those code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This must be helpful

```
global $wpdb; 
$request = "A" 
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE '$request%'
        AND post_type = 'event'
        AND post_status = 'publish'; 
        "
);
```

Comment: Thanks Brijesh Paliwal for the quick answer. Where shall i put this?

Comment: I suppose on the page on which you want to get the result, it should be your post list page for events